# In Angular, how to add Validator to FormControl after control is created?

Tags: angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms

We have a component that has a dynamically built form. The code to add a control with validators might look like this:

```js
var c = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
```

But let's say that I want to add 2nd Validator **later**. How can we accomplish this? We cannot find any documentation on this online. I did find though in the form controls there is `setValidators`

```js
this.form.controls["firstName"].setValidators
```

but it is not clear how to add a new or custom validator.

Answer (score 197, accepted):

You simply pass the `FormControl` an array of validators.

Here's an example showing how you can add validators to an existing FormControl:

```js
this.form.controls["firstName"].setValidators([Validators.minLength(1), Validators.maxLength(30)]);
```

Note, this will reset any existing validators you added when you created the `FormControl`.

**Angular 12 update**

Since Angular 12, if you want to add new validators to the form without removing the existing validators, you can use `addValidator`:

```js
this.form.controls["firstName"].addValidators([Validators.minLength(1), Validators.maxLength(30)]);
```

Comment: ha...sometimes you look at something so long it is best to just step away. THANK YOU!!

Comment: This really solved the problem that I was trying to fix for a long time. Thanks a ton for sharing!

Comment: Is there a way to remove validation

Comment: Cheers. If you have css in the field use `.patchValue()` after so the the styling refresh.

Comment: dude it is like a hack, consider a scenario where there are 50 fields or more generated from xsd sent from server which has basic validators like max length or min length and then there are dynamic mandatory fields based on user then i can't get existing validtors or push to existing validators.

Comment: any way to do this without overriding the old ones? or any way to append the new ones?

Comment: @danday74, check out Eduard Void's answer at the bottom of this question. Should be accepted answer imo. He explains how to do what you need to know, which I also needed to know how to do.

Comment: Note that this will clear all existing validators that may have been set during form initialization.

Comment: I had to also call `.updateValueAndValidity()` on the form control after setting the new validators.

Comment: Explains how to wipe and reset validators, not add validators

Comment: addValidators() was added in v12.2.0 https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1220-rc0-2021-07-28

Answer (score 142):

To add onto what @Delosdos has posted.

**Set** a validator for a control in the `FormGroup`:
    `this.myForm.controls['controlName'].setValidators([Validators.required])`

**Remove** the validator from the control in the FormGroup:
`this.myForm.controls['controlName'].clearValidators()`

**Update** the FormGroup once you have run either of the above lines.
`this.myForm.controls['controlName'].updateValueAndValidity()`

This is an amazing way to programmatically set your form validation.

Comment: For me it worked without the last line, I'm pretty sure new versions of Angular update the form validity by themselves now. But thanks for telling us about the `updateValueAndValidity` method, might come handy one day!

Comment: @NinoFiliu `updateValueAndValidity` is still used to perform the validation, and isn't handled any differently in newer versions of Angular.  What happens is `setValidators` updates the validators, but doesn't run a validation check, and then you use `updateValueAndValidity` to perform the validation.  You must be setting the validators at a point where change detection handles it for you, but you'll find using `updateValueAndValidity` on the group or control depending what validator you just set crucial - https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19622#issuecomment-341547884.

Comment: I'm on Angular 6 and couldn't make it work without the `updateValueAndValidity`. Thanks @shammelburg !

Comment: On Angular 7 and it also wouldn't work for me without the last update line.

Comment: Yes. It is working without `updateValueAndValidity()`, but in some cases, it does not. if you added `updateValueAndValidity()` after `setValidators()` It will **immediately affect the changes related to control**. So it is better to add updateValueAndValidity()`.

Comment: In my case, it worked only when I **removed** `updateValueAndValidity()`.

Comment: First I put all this in `AfterViewInit`, which did not work. Then I put the logic in `OnInit`, then it worked.

Comment: Explains how to wipe and reset validators, not add validators

Answer (score 119):

If you are using reactiveFormModule and have formGroup defined like this:

```
public exampleForm = new FormGroup({
        name: new FormControl('Test name', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]),
        email: new FormControl('test@example.com', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]),
        age: new FormControl(45, [Validators.min(18), Validators.max(65)])
});
```

than you are able to add a new validator (**and keep old ones**) to FormControl with this approach:

```
this.exampleForm.get('age').setValidators([
        Validators.pattern('^[0-9]*$'),
        this.exampleForm.get('age').validator
]);
this.exampleForm.get('email').setValidators([
        Validators.email,
        this.exampleForm.get('email').validator
]);
```

FormControl.validator returns a compose validator containing all previously defined validators.

Comment: Imo this should be the accepted answer. It demonstrates how to add validators like OP requested, but also shows you how to retain previously set validators; which was the first thing I googled how to do after I read the accepted answer, because I didn't want to overwrite some validators I already had, but still needed to programatically add additional ones. Thank you for this answer @Eduard Void

Comment: I agree with my predecessor. The question was how to **add** new validator to control form, not how to **replace** it.

Comment: I did `control.setValidators(control.validator ? [ control.validator, Validators.email ] : Validators.email);` to get around strict null checks

Answer (score 7):

In addition to Eduard Void answer here's the `addValidators` method:

```
declare module '@angular/forms' {
  interface FormControl {
    addValidators(validators: ValidatorFn[]): void;
  }
}

FormControl.prototype.addValidators = function(this: FormControl, validators: ValidatorFn[]) {
  if (!validators || !validators.length) {
    return;
  }

  const old_validator = this.validator;

  this.clearValidators();
  this.setValidators( old_validator ? [ old_validator , ...validators ] : validators );
};
```

Using it you can set validators dynamically:

```
some_form_control.addValidators([ first_validator, second_validator ]);
some_form_control.addValidators([ third_validator ]);
```

Comment: This is very good solution for Angular 12 prior version but *this.clearValidators();* will remove the existing validators and add new passed validator.

Answer (score 7):

If you need to remove some existing validation on the added form control then call below function on the control

```js
this.form.controls["name"].clearValidators();
```

After that you need to call below function to update the form controls and it will be effective immediately on the form controls.

```js
this.form.controls['name'].updateValueAndValidity();
```

If you need to add some validation on the already added form control then call the below function on the control

```js
this.signupForm.controls['name'].setValidators([Validators.required]);
```

After that call `updateValueAndValidity()` function immediately, so it can be reflected instantly.

Answer (score 5):

I think the selected answer is not correct, as the original question is "how to add a new validator after create the formControl".

As far as I know, that's not possible. The only thing you can do, is create the array of validators dynamicaly.

But what we miss is to have a function addValidator() to not override the validators already added to the formControl. If anybody has an answer for that requirement, would be nice to be posted here.

Comment: You'd think `control.setValidators(control.validator ? [ control.validator, Validators.email ] : Validators.email);` would work.

Comment: See @Eduard Void 's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276815/6656422

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to first get all the validators in the form control and assign a new validatorFn to it when needed code will go like this.

```
//get existing validators and assign a new validator

const formControl = this.form.controls["firstName"];

 const validators: ValidatorFn[] = !!formControl.validator ?
  [formControl.validator, Validators.required] :
  [Validators.required];

formControl.setValidators(validators);
```

formControl.validtor holds the existing validators (not asyncValidators)
we check if it's not null using ternary and add to it ( here we add the required validator to it), otherwise, we just assign our new validator

Answer (score 0):

Updating validators based on other Form Control's values.

First setting the form:

```
  form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    firstName: new FormControl<string>(null),
    lastName: new FormControl<string>(null),
  });
```

then on init:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form.get('firstName').valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
      if (value) {
        this.form.get('lastName').setValidators(Validators.nullValidator);
      } else {
        this.form.get('lastName').setValidators(Validators.required);
      }
      this.form.get('lastName').updateValueAndValidity({ emitEvent: false });
    });
    this.form.get('lastName').valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
      if (value) {
        this.form.get('firstName').setValidators(Validators.nullValidator);
      } else {
        this.form.get('firstName').setValidators(Validators.required);
      }
      this.form.get('firstName').updateValueAndValidity({ emitEvent: false });
    });
  }
```

It's important to add `{ emitEvent: false }` so you don't get the *Maximum call stack size exceeded* error