# Angular - assign custom validator to a FormGroup

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation

I need to assign a custom validator to a FormGroup. I can do this at the time the FormGroup is created like this:

```
let myForm : FormGroup;

myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        myControl1: defaultValue,
        myControl2: defaultValue
      }, { validator: this.comparisonValidator })

comparisonValidator(g: FormGroup) {
      if (g.get('myControl1').value > g.get('myControl2'.value)) {
        g.controls['myControl1'].setErrors({ 'value2GreaterThanValue1': true });
        return;
      }
}
```

I have a situation though where I need to add the custom validator *after* I've instantiated the FormGroup, so I'm trying to do this after instantiating `myForm`, instead of adding the validator when the form is instantiated:

```
let myForm : FormGroup;

myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        myControl1: defaultValue,
        myControl2: defaultValue
      })

this.myForm.validator = this.comparisonValidator;
```

This gives me a compiler error:

```
Type '(g: FormGroup) => void' is not assignable to type 'ValidatorFn'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ValidationErrors'.
```

How do I assign a validator to my `FormGroup` so that the `formGroup` is passed as the argument to my `comparisonValidator` function?

**Update** - I've added a line showing where I'm doing a `setErrors` in my `comparisonValidator`, to make it clearer exactly how I'm trying to set a validation error.

Comment: Adding dynamic validator can be done using [setValidators()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38797547/6426617). but specific for a particular control you can update at a time

Comment: You get this error because you return `void` from your `comparisonValidator` function. Change the function to return `null` on the last line (not inside the if-statement) and the error should be gone.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I've created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-custom-validation) take a look.

In the component.ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder,FormGroup, ValidationErrors, ValidatorFn} from '@angular/forms'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  myForm: FormGroup;
  defaultValue = 20;

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
  this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        myControl1: this.defaultValue,
        myControl2: this.defaultValue
      });
      debugger
      this.myForm.setValidators(this.comparisonValidator())
}

 public comparisonValidator() : ValidatorFn{
       return (group: FormGroup): ValidationErrors => {
          const control1 = group.controls['myControl1'];
          const control2 = group.controls['myControl2'];
          if (control1.value !== control2.value) {
             control2.setErrors({notEquivalent: true});
          } else {
             control2.setErrors(null);
          }
          return;
    };
 }
}
```

In the component.html file

```
<div>
  <form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <input formControlName="myControl1" type="number">
    <input formControlName="myControl2"  type="number">
    <br>Errors: {{myForm.get('myControl2').errors | json}}
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Anuradha. To clarify what I'm asking, I'm trying to only add the validator *after* the `FormGroup` is instantiated, instead of adding it *when* the form is instantiated. I've edited the question a little to make it clearer.

Comment: @ChrisHalcrow I've updated the ansewer take alook. nd You can find a working example in [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-custom-validation).

Comment: Shouldn't the `ValidatorFn` **return** the errors object? In this case, the `ValidatorFn` calls `setErrors()`, but doesn't `return;` anything

Comment: are you able to set `(group: FormGroup): ValidationErrors` to `ValidatorsFn` ? that seems to give me errors, it only allows `(control: FormControl): ValidationErrors`

Answer (score 9):

For setting any validators (predefined or customs) after instantiating the formGroup, you will need to use the `setValiators()` method of `FormGroup`, f.e.:

```
  let myFormGroup = this.    _fb.group({
      control1: new FormControl('1', [])
    });
  myFormGroup.setValidators(this.customValidators());
  customValidators(): ValidatorFn {
   let myFun = (cc: FormGroup): ValidationErrors => {
     if(cc.valid) return null;
     else return {something: 'someError'};
   };
   return myFun;
  }
```

Comment: Better solution than returning any from validator.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to @Anuradha Gunasekara - his answer is the most correct and complete solution. A 'quick fix' for my error was just to add a return type of `any` on the validator. I can still assign the custom validator to the `FormGroup`, and the `FormGroup` will be passed implicitly as the argument to my custom validator. This code will work:

```
let myForm : FormGroup;

myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
           myControl1: defaultValue,
           myControl2: defaultValue
         })

this.myForm.validator = this.comparisonValidator;

comparisonValidator(g: FormGroup) : any {
      if (g.get('myControl1').value > g.get('myControl2'.value)) {
        g.controls['myControl1'].setErrors({ 'value2GreaterThanValue1': true });
      }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Remove all form control white space form Form Group**

**custom validator :**

```
    export function formGroupRemoveWhitespaceValidator(form: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null {
    const keys: string[] = Object.keys(form.controls);

    if (keys.length) {
        keys.forEach(k => {
            let control = form.controls[k];
            
            if (control && control.value && !control.value.replace(/\s/g, '').length) {
                control.setValue('');
            }
        });
    }

    return null;
}
```

**component :**

```
let myForm : FormGroup;

myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
           myControl1: defaultValue,
           myControl2: defaultValue
         }, { validators: formGroupRemoveWhitespaceValidator });
```

Answer (score 0):

These answers doesn't work for me, because I have other validators too. In my usecase, I have to set the errors also for the opposite field.
Perhaps it doesn't met the requirements of the OP exactly, but it hopefully helps others (like me), which landed on this site.

Here my is solution, which can be safely combined with other validators and also ensure, that the opposite field got an update.

```
// ...
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
        myControl1: this.formBuilder.control(defaultValue, [Validators.required, this.validateIsEqualTo('myControl2')]),
        myControl2: this.formBuilder.control(defaultValue, this.validateIsEqualTo('myControl1')
      });

this.form.get('myControl1').valueChanges
   .pipe(
      takeUntil(this.destroy$),
      disinctUntilChanged())
   .subscribe(() => this.form.get('myControl2').updateValueAndValidity());

this.form.get('myControl2').valueChanges
   .pipe(
      takeUntil(this.destroy$),
      disinctUntilChanged())
   .subscribe(() => this.form.get('myControl1').updateValueAndValidity());
// ...

public validateIsEqualTo(otherComponentId): ValidatorFn {
   return (control: FormControl): ValidationErrors => {
      const otherControl = this.form.get(otherComponentId);
      return control.value !== otherControl.value ? {notEquivalent: true} : null;
   }
}
```

Comment: @aokp - Will this work ? the line const otherControl = group.controls[otherComponentId];, how are you accessing group without passing it ?

Comment: Sorry, trying to understand why other solutions do not work for you. Would it not be better to have a validator on the formGroup rather than having to pass other control names in the validator ? This way there would be no overhead of passing around control names if the controls list ever increases.

Comment: They other answers don't work for me, because of the "double" relation. A change in `controlA` will trigger in a check `controlB`. And then it is endless loop. Special note: I need unique errors and my checks aren't just a equal-check. I simplified it for StackOverflow-answer.

Comment: tldr; all other answers causing a endless loop for my use cases. :)

Answer (score 0):

The answers from this post causes me a problem such as the data type
becoming incompatible. I modify a bit in the below. Now This fits my case.

```
  constructor(){
      this.form = this.fb.group({
      password: ['', [Validators.required]],
      confirmPassword: ['', [Validators.required]]
      })
      this.form.setValidators(this.formGroupValidator)
  }


  formGroupValidator: ValidatorFn = (
    control: AbstractControl
  ): ValidationErrors | null => {
    if (control.value.password !== control.value.confirmPassword) {
      control.get('confirmPassword')!.setErrors({ notEquivalent: true });
    } else {
      control.get('confirmPassword')!.setErrors(null);
    }
    return null;
  };
```