# Angular formControl validators that depend on other formcontrols

Tags: angular, validation, angular-forms, form-control

I need to create a form that will contain 2 dates, dateFrom and dateTo.
**The condition for validation is that dateFrom cannot be after dateTo and dateTo cannot be before dateFrom.**

So I created a form group with two form controls and a validator in common that will check this condition.

```
export class DateRangeSelector {

    dateForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
         dateFrom: new FormControl({ year: 2017, month: 10 },[this.dateValidator.bind(this)]),
         dateTo: new FormControl({ year: 2020, month: 11 }, [this.dateValidator.bind(this)])
    });

dateValidator(control: FormControl): { [s: string]: boolean } {
    const valueDateFrom = this.dateForm.get('dateForm').value;
    const valueDateTo = this.dateForm.get('dateTo').value;
    if (valueDateFrom && valueDateTo) {
        //please ignore the fact that value is {year: x, month: y}, I need  to parse
        const dateFrom = moment(valueDateFrom);
        const dateTo = moment(valueDateTo);
        if (dateFrom.isAfter(dateTo)) {
            return { invalidDate: true };
        }
    }
    return null;
    }
}
```

My problem is that **this.dateForm** is not defined (not in the context) when validators try to validate.  And I don't understand because I *binded* the method in the *validators declaration*.

Comment: if you want to validate multiple formcontrols add your validator to the formgroup.
simliar case is answered in this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51094146/angular-assign-custom-validator-to-a-formgroup

Comment: @enno.void thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the reason `this.dateForm` comes as undefined because the Validatdor gets executed while creation of the individual Form Controls itself, i.e. when the property `dateForm` is still under creation.

You can validate this by doing this in your validator in existing code.

```
  dateValidator() {
    console.log(this.dateForm);
  }
```

You would see the group geting printed after two `undefined`

A good approach to handle this would be use a group validatdor, like:

```
dateForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup(
  {
    dateFrom: new FormControl({ year: 2017, month: 10 }),
    dateTo: new FormControl({ year: 2020, month: 11 }),
  },
  this.dateValidator.bind(this)
);

dateValidator(group: FormGroup) {
  const valueDateFrom = group.get('dateFrom').value;
  const valueDateTo = group.get('dateTo').value;
  if (valueDateFrom && valueDateTo) {
    //please ignore the fact that value is {year: x, month: y}, I need  to parse
    const dateFrom = new Date(valueDateFrom).getTime(); // moment(valueDateFrom)
    const dateTo = new Date(valueDateTo).getTime(); // moment(valueDateTo);
    if (dateFrom > dateTo) {
      console.log('Error =====> ');
      return { invalidDate: true };
    }
  }

  console.log('Success =====> ');
  return null;
}
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mwc8vf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 3):

you can define your control as

```
new FormGroup({
        dateFrom: new FormControl('', [validateStartResult]),
        dateTo: new FormControl('', [validateEndResult]),
})
```

then create separate file for validation

```
import {AbstractControl, ValidationErrors, ValidatorFn} from "@angular/forms";

enum ValidationFor {
    end = 'end',
    start = 'start'
}

export const validateEndResult: ValidatorFn = (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    return validateResult(control, ValidationFor.end);
}
export const validateStartResult: ValidatorFn = (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    return validateResult(control, ValidationFor.start);
}

function validateResult(control, currentValidation: ValidationFor): ValidationErrors | null {
    const startControl = control?.root?.get('dateFrom');
    const endControl = control?.root?.get('dateTo');

    const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    const startTimeStamp = new Date(startControl?.value).getTime(); // configurations yours date
    const endTimeStamp = new Date(endControl?.value).getTime(); // configurations yours date

    const error: { [key: string]: boolean } = {};
    let hasError = false;

    if (startTimeStamp > endTimeStamp) { // main codition
        if (currentValidation === ValidationFor.end) {
            error.endResult = true
        }
        if (currentValidation === ValidationFor.start) {
            error.startResult = true
        }
        hasError = true;
    }

    return hasError ? error : null;
}
```

you can follow this guide to complete own validation

Answer (score 0):

After checking formGroup validators:

dateForm: FormGroup;

```
dateForm: FormGroup;

constructor(formBuilder: FormBuilder, private toastService: ToastService) {
    this.dateForm = formBuilder.group({
        dateFrom: { year: 2017, month: 10 },
        dateTo: { year: 2018, month: 11 }
    });
    this.dateForm.setValidators(this.dateValidator());
}

dateValidator(): ValidatorFn {
    return (group: FormGroup): ValidationErrors => {
        const controlDateFrom = group.controls.dateFrom;
        const controlDateTo = group.controls.dateTo;
        if (controlDateFrom.value && controlDateTo.value) {
            const dateFrom = moment(controlDateFrom.value);
            const dateTo = moment(controlDateTo.value);
            if (dateFrom.isAfter(dateTo)) {
                controlDateFrom.setErrors({ invalidDateRange: true});
                controlDateFrom.setErrors({ invalidDateRange: true});
            }else{
                controlDateFrom.setErrors(null);
                controlDateTo.setErrors(null);
            }
        }
        return;
    };
}
```

This solution is particulary interesting because as it is binded to the component I can show a toast for example when the date is wrong. Or I can format the date value before it's setted and this way avoid all errors.