# Argument of type '{ validators: (formGroup: FormGroup) => void; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ValidatorFn

Tags: angular, typescript

I am making a form with confirm password validation in angular 13 and the validation keeps throwing me this error in the ts file.

I coded my FormGroup as follows

```
registerForm = new FormGroup(
  {
    age: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.min(14)]),
    name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z]')]),
    username: new FormControl('', [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(10),
      UsernameValidators.cannotContainSpace,
    ]),
    password: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]),
    confirmPassword: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
  },
  { validators: PasswordValidators.mustMatch('password', 'confirmPassword') }
);
```

and my password validator as follows

```
export class PasswordValidators {
  static mustMatch(controlName: string, matchingControlName: string) {
    return (formGroup: FormGroup) => {
      const control = formGroup.controls[controlName];

      const matchingControl = formGroup.controls[matchingControlName];

      if (matchingControl.errors && !matchingControl.errors['mustMatch']) {
        // return if another validator has already found an error on the matchingControl

        return;
      }

      // set error on matchingControl if validation fails

      if (control.value !== matchingControl.value) {
        matchingControl.setErrors({ mustMatch: true });
      } else {
        matchingControl.setErrors(null);
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: What are the errors? I'm not sure I fully understand where exactly the problem lies. Please add some more detail! Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular - assign custom validator to a FormGroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51094146/angular-assign-custom-validator-to-a-formgroup)

Answer (score 3):

`PasswordValidators.mustMatch` is not a proper `ValidatorFn`, see the [docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/ValidatorFn). It needs to return either `ValidationErrors` or `null`.

```
export class PasswordValidators {
  static mustMatch(controlName: string, matchingControlName: string) {
    return (formGroup: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null => {
      const control = formGroup.controls[controlName];

      const matchingControl = formGroup.controls[matchingControlName];

      if (matchingControl.errors && !matchingControl.errors['mustMatch']) {
        // return if another validator has already found an error on the matchingControl

        return null;
      }

      // return error if validation fails

      let errors = null;
      if (control.value !== matchingControl.value) {
        errors = { mustMatch: true };
      }
      matchingControl.setErrors(errors);
      return errors;
    };
  }
}
```