# Form group validator is overriding the form control validator in Angular 10

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms, angular10, customvalidator

I am using angular 10 reactive forms. I have around 5 form controls. Each has its own validations.
I am also required to compare values of two form control and based on the input value, need to assign each of these two controls errors.
So I added a form group custom validator.
But this is overriding the individual validator on the two form controls of concerns. The individual validators for other form controls are working fine.

I have used the structure similar to the selected answer in the post by Anuradha Gunasekara :

[Angular - assign custom validator to a FormGroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51094146/angular-assign-custom-validator-to-a-formgroup)

however, setting *SetErrors(null)* in the custom validator removes validations added at the individual formControl level.

Is there any other way to remove just that particular error?
Apologies if it's not clear enough, it is my first post. Do let me know if any further context is required, Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: can you please add a stackblitz example here with your problem.