# Form group validator is overriding the form control validator in Angular 11

Tags: angular

I am facing the problem as described in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73821919/form-group-validator-is-overriding-the-form-control-validator-in-angular-10)

I am trying to add a validator to a form group in which I have already 3 validators on form controls.
So I have a form group with 6 controls, 3 of them have a required validator. And I want to validate globally my form to check if a date period is correctly described, so I add a validator to my form group.

Here is an example of code :

```
        this.identifierForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            id: [],
            type: [null, Validators.required],
            value: [null, Validators.required],
            validFrom: [],
            validUntil: [],
            authority: [null, Validators.required],
        });
        this.identifierForm.setValidators(
            FormValidator.dateOrderValidator(
                this.identifierForm,
                'validFrom',
                'validUntil',
                this.i18nService
            )
        );
```

This results in only the form group validator to work. The form control validators are just ommited.
If I delete my form group validator, everything is working well in my form controls validators.

How can I do to "add" validator to my form group without overriding the included form controls validators?

I saw that angular 12 added the "addValidators" method to the FormGroup but I am not able to use this version at the moment.

EDIT:
I just tryed to define my formgroup validator at instantiation timebut result is still the same

```
        this.identifierForm = this.formBuilder.group(
            {
                id: [],
                type: [null, Validators.required],
                value: [null, Validators.required],
                validFrom: [],
                validUntil: [],
                authority: [null, Validators.required],
            },
            {
                validators: [
                    FormValidator.dateOrderValidator('validFrom', 'validUntil', this.i18nService),
                ],
            }
        );
```

Here is my validator :

```
dateOrderValidator(
        startDateFieldName: string,
        endDateFieldName: string,
        i18nService: DngI18nService
    ): ValidatorFn {
        return (formGroup: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null => {
            resetErrors(formGroup);
            const startDate = formGroup.controls[startDateFieldName]?.value;
            const endDate = formGroup.controls[endDateFieldName]?.value;
            if (Date.parse(startDate) >= Date.parse(endDate)) {
                formGroup.controls[startDateFieldName].setErrors({
                    error: i18nService.instant('invalidDatePeriod') as string,
                });
                formGroup.controls[endDateFieldName].setErrors({
                    error: i18nService.instant('invalidDatePeriod') as string,
                });
                return { error: i18nService.instant('invalidForm') as string };
            }
            return null;
        };
    },
```

Comment: This is because `setValidators` removes all existing validators. So, either set all validators via `setValidators` or define the formgroup validator at the time of instantiating (check the syntax for it).

Comment: @derstauner I tryed but problem is still the same. My formgroup validator overrides my formcontrol validators

Comment: So you are doing `resetErrors` at the start of the validator, which presumably deletes all previous errors of the other validators. Have you tried not doing that? xD

Comment: Hummmm...., you are totally right !!! It works now.
Thank you