# Angular - How to validate between issuedDate and expiryDate

Tags: angular, validation, ngx-bootstrap

I am implementing ngx-bootstrap datepicker in Angular-14. Then I want to validate between IssuedDate and ExpiryDate of Drivers Licence.

I have this code.

component.ts:

```
  minIssuedDate!: Date;
  minExpiryDate!: Date;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) {
    this.minIssuedDate = new Date();
    this.minExpiryDate = new Date();
    this.minIssuedDate.setDate(this.minIssuedDate.getDate());
    this.minExpiryDate.setDate(this.minExpiryDate.getDate() + 1);
  }

  createProfile() {
    this.createProfileForm = this.fb.group({
      issuedDate: ['', [Validators.required],
      expiryDate: ['', [Validators.required]]
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createProfile();
  }
```

component.html:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="issuedDate">Issued Date</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i></span>
        </div>
        <input type="text"
        placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY"
        class="form-control"
        formControlName='issuedDate'
        bsDatepicker
        [minDate]="minIssuedDate"
        [bsConfig]="{ isAnimated: true, dateInputFormat: 'DD-MM-YYYY', returnFocusToInput: true, showClearButton: true, clearPosition: 'right' }">
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="fc['issuedDate'].touched && fc['issuedDate'].invalid" class="alert alert-danger">
        <div *ngIf="fc['issuedDate'].errors && fc['issuedDate'].errors['required']">Issued Date field is required!</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="expiryDate">Expiry Date<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i></span>
        </div>
        <input type="text"
        placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY"
        class="form-control"
        formControlName='expiryDate'
        bsDatepicker
        [minDate]="minExpiryDate"
        [bsConfig]="{ isAnimated: true, dateInputFormat: 'DD-MM-YYYY', returnFocusToInput: true, showClearButton: true, clearPosition: 'right' }">
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="fc['expiryDate'].touched && fc['expiryDate'].invalid" class="alert alert-danger">
        <div *ngIf="fc['expiryDate'].errors && fc['expiryDate'].errors['required']">Expiry Date field is required!</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I validate that issuedDate must not be greater than ExpiryDate?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try setting a custom validator on the form group? Like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51094146/angular-assign-custom-validator-to-a-formgroup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom validator and apply it to `createProfileForm`

**Ts**

```
createProfile() {
    this.createProfileForm = this.fb.group(
      {
        issuedDate: ['', [Validators.required]],
        expiryDate: ['', [Validators.required]],
      },
      { validators: this.dateValidator }
    );
}

dateValidator(group: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null {
    const fromCtrl = group.get('issuedDate')!;
    const toCtrl = group.get('expiryDate')!;

    return new Date(fromCtrl.value) > new Date(toCtrl.value)
      ? { issueDateGreater: 'issue date is greater than expiry date' }
      : null;
}
```

**Html**

```
<span *ngIf="createProfileForm!.hasError('issueDateGreater')">issue date is greater than expiry date</span>
```