# The [required] tag is emitting an event every time it changes from true to false

Tags: html, angular, forms

I have an Angular form initialized with something like this

```
buildForm() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
        value1: this.formBuilder.control(null),
        value2: this.formBuilder.control(false)
    });
}
```

and I use a `[required]` in the tag in the html where I have two conditions, first is an object with a true/false required and the second being another value in the form (which can be updated in the ts or by a user).

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
    <div *ngIf="valuesObject.value1.display">
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-select formControlName="value1"
                        [required]="valuesObject.value1.required || form.value.value2">
                <mat-option [value]="null"> empty <mat-option>
                <mat-option [value]="1"> option 1 <mat-option>
            </mat-select> 
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
</div>
```

Every time the `[required]` flips from false -> true or true -> false, it sends an event to my `form.valueChanges` which then sends a call to the server because it thinks that data has been updated. Is there a way to ignore this event or capture it so I can set a flag to ignore it within the `.valueChanges`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `formControl`, then you don't need to use the [required] attribute as well. Try to change your app logic in a way, that you use the `formControl` object to handle the required attribute - it's the proper way.

```
this.form.controls["value1"].setValidators([Validators.required]);
```

and to clear it

```
this.form.controls["value1"].clearValidators()
```

**You need to update the form after this, to properly make the changes:**

```
this.form.controls['value1'].updateValueAndValidity()
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38797414/in-angular-how-to-add-validator-to-formcontrol-after-control-is-created)

**Update**

As you said, the said check is quite frequent, and you whish to keep it in the template: in that case, I still suggest using a **custom validator**, in which you can encapsulate your logic.

See [Cross field validation](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#cross-field-validation) tutorial from the docs, for reactive forms (as you said you change the field's value from the code side too):

```
const heroForm = new FormGroup({
  'value1': new FormControl(),
  'value2': new FormControl()
}, { validators: myRequiredValidation });

export const : myRequiredValidation = (control: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null => {
  const value1 = control.get('value1');
  const 'value2' = control.get('value2');

  return <your logic> ? { myRequiredValidation: true } : null;
};
```

Comment: I am aware of this solution, but in my code I could have 10 places (which could increase in the future) that I am changing/checking when value1 (which could be in a parent component where my `valuesObject` doesn't exist) should be required/not required. plus I need to watch when value2 changes either by my logic (which I am ignoring most of those events) or by a user's events. having it in the html is easier for management and maintainability.

Comment: I see your point. I still respectfully disaggree with keeping validation logic in the template though: you can utilize custom validators to encapsulate your validation logic, and still use ony the formControl api. But I can understand if that's not what you are looking for, sadly I don't really know a good trick to go around this problem in any other way :( updated my answer with a custom validator option.